# Azure Media Services Live Video Streaming download stored video

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

i need to download a video that was live streaming with Azure Media Services, and saved as an event, is it possible to download it? i dont have experience with videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's not quite correct.  To really "download" the live archive, you have to run it through an Encoding job to convert it from a live archive (fragmented MP4 format) into a single MP4 file (or other format) that you can actually download.

What I would do is use the Azure Media Services Explorer tool (aka.ms/amse) to get the Live Event's underlying AssetID and submit that to an encoding job. The issue with the portal is that we don't currently give you a way to click through from the "Live Event" recording to the actual stored Asset (I'll get somebody to fix that! or provide a simple, Encode for Download button).

In the portal you can also "search" in the Assets list for the underlying asset. It should be named {channelname}-{live event name}.  You can then click on that and use the "Encode" button to submit a single-bitrate encoding job.

Hope that helps!

-John D.

Comment: ohh ok, thanks i hope we can have a quick download method soon, for now i'll do a work around for it

Answer (score 0):

you can find all of your live streaming recordings in Azure portal.

They are located under settings -> assets

You will see url that you can use to download the video.

[image: Azure media portal]

Answer (score 0):

Azure is suitable for streaming and hosting your videos. But, unfortunately, Microsoft has scheduled Azure’s retirement on June 30, 2024 — which will effectively mean you will no longer be able to save your videos there.

But we have several good alternatives to keep your business up and running.

If you’re still looking for an Azure Media Services alternative, you can check the following platforms to migrate your content.

1. VPlayed.com
2. Amazon Elemental Media Services
3. Southworks
4. Blendvision

Hope it helps!

PS: This is not a sponsored post. I took this list from Google search and multiple websites.